# React: Added http-proxy-middleware to get information from different API endpoints, but now I have a CANNOT /get error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, http-proxy-middleware

I read this [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually?noredirect=1&lq=1), and while it explained why I'm facing the issue, I'm not too sure what the best approach is here.

I set up http-proxy-middleware as a workaround for pulling information from different servers. Currently, I'm pulling information from firebase to get information about my users, as well as my localhost:8000 server for other information.

However, after setting up http-proxy-middleware, I'm facing two issues:

1. When I type "localhost:3001/signup" into my browser, I get a page that says **Cannot GET /signup**
2. When I type in "localhost:3001/user/username" it's displaying the entire JSON response, rather than allowing me to use the data to render out my component.
   (image below)[image: JSON response http-proxy-middleware issue]

This is my **setUpProxy.js**

```
module.exports = function(app){
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/api' , { target : 'http://localhost:8000', changeOrigin: true}));
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/user', { target : 'https://us-central1-auth-development-2fa3c.cloudfunctions.net/api', changeOrigin: true}))
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/users', { target : 'https://us-central1-auth-development-2fa3c.cloudfunctions.net/api', changeOrigin: true}))
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/scream', { target : 'https://us-central1-auth-development-2fa3c.cloudfunctions.net/api', changeOrigin: true}))
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/screams', { target : 'https://us-central1-auth-development-2fa3c.cloudfunctions.net/api', changeOrigin: true}))
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/login', { target : 'https://us-central1-auth-development-2fa3c.cloudfunctions.net/api', changeOrigin: true}))
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/signup', { target : 'https://us-central1-auth-development-2fa3c.cloudfunctions.net/api', changeOrigin: true}))

}
```

This is my **App.js** router set up

```
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
          <QuickstartProvider>
            <Route exact path="/" component={home} />
            <AuthRoute exact path="/frontpage" component={frontpage} />
            <AuthRoute exact path="/login" component={login} />
            <AuthRoute exact path="/signup" component={signup} />
            <Route exact path="/users/:handle" component={user} />
            </QuickstartProvider>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and if this helps, this is my code for my /user/username page. Although I don't think the issue is here.

```
class user extends Component {
  state = {
    profile: null,
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    const handle = this.props.match.params.handle;
    this.props.getUserData(handle);
    axios
      .get(`/user/${handle}`)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          profile: res.data.user,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
  render() {
    const { screams, loading } = this.props.data;

    const screamsMarkup = loading ? (
      <p> loading data... </p>
    ) : screams === null ? (
      <p>No posts from this user</p>
    ) : (
      screams.map((scream) => <Scream key={scream.screamId} scream={scream} />)
    );
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.profile === null ? (
          <p>Loading Profile...</p>
        ) : (
          <StaticProfile profile={this.state.profile} />
        )}
        {screamsMarkup}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

user.propTypes = {
  getUserData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  data: state.data,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUserData })(user);
```

I'm quite new to react and this is my first time using http-proxy-middleware, so apologies if I didn't explain my problem as best as possible.

Thank you in advance!